# how to correctly use stub for testing in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, stubbing

So, I have a method in a class as follow:

```
def installation_backlog
  Api::Dashboards::InstallationsBacklog.new(operational_district_id, officer_id).backlog_tasks
end
```

And I want to spec it. So, I just wrote an RSpec test to test it as follow:

```
it "should call a new instance of InstallationsBacklog with the backlog_tasks method" do
  expect_any_instance_of(Api::Dashboards::InstallationsBacklog).to receive(:backlog_tasks)
  @installation_officer.installation_backlog # @installation_officer is a new instance of the container class.
end
```

And this is working.

However, I began to wonder if this was a correct way of doing it. Like: am I sure that even if I stub the wrong ( probably inexistent ) method, and test for it, will it pass or fail?

*I tried it, it passed*

So, if later, the method name gets changed, there is no way for this test to detect that.

**So, here is the question**: How can I be sure that a RSpec stubbed method is actually existent in a code?

Comment: I don't think you stubbed the method.  Stubbing would be done by allow_any_instance_of(Api::Dashboards::InstallationsBacklog).to receive(:backlog_tasks).and_return(desired_return_value).

Comment: I would use `allow(Api::Dashboards::InstallationsBacklog).to receive(:new).and_return(backlog_double)` and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd set it up. Might help..

```
let(:backlog) {
  double('Backlog', backlog_tasks: [])
}

before do
  allow(Api::Dashboards::InstallationsBacklog).to receive(:new).
    and_return(backlog)
end

it 'instantiates InstallationBacklog' do
  expect(Api::Dashboards::InstallationBacklog).to receive(:new).
    with(operational_district_id, officer_id)

  @installation_officer.installation_backlog
end

it 'calls backlog_tasks on instance of InstallationBacklog' do
  expect(backlog).to receive(:backlog_tasks)

  @installation_officer.installation_backlog
end
```

Comment: Great, I understand this angle here... however, if for example, there is no instance method `backlog_tasks` on `Api::Dashboards::InstallationsBacklog`, this test will still pass, and I want it to fail

Comment: @SunnyK that's fine. Test your `InstallationBacklog` class separately and that will catch such a scenario. It shouldn't be the responsibility of this spec.

Comment: @SunnyK: You might want to use an [`instance_double`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-instance-double) instead of a simple `double` to verify the  existence of the stubbed method.